# How to call a method within a method from another method?

Tags: javascript

In a javascript file I have this:

```
Work.expenses= function (params)
{
    function deleteExpenses() 
    {
      //here I want to call the loadExpensesList method
    }
}

Work.expensesList= function (params)  
{
    function loadExpensesList() 
    {
     //this is the method I want to call
    }
}
```

How do I call the loadExpensesList method in the deleteExpenses method?
Thank you!

Comment: `loadExpensesList` isn't really a method; it's just an inner function that you have to make public if you want to call it from outside.

Comment: You can't unless you expose it to a higher scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
Work.expenses= function (params)
{
    function deleteExpenses() 
    {
      Work.expensesList('something')();
    }
}

Work.expensesList= function (params)  
{
    function loadExpensesList() 
    {

    }
    return loadExpensesList;
}
```

You can try like this. But can be better by understanding the requirement.